# Loosen the rules around suggesting tag synonyms

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms

I tried to create a tag synonym for [multiplatform](/questions/tagged/multiplatform) and [multi-platform](/questions/tagged/multi-platform), but I'm denied because I don't have 5 upvotes in the tag.

I think the restrictions should be eased up for high-rep users (say, 10k+) because we are just trying to improve the site.  I can't see myself getting 5 votes in the tag and then remembering to suggest the synonym again at a later date, and anyway it just submits the suggestion for community voting - it doesn't actually create the synonym immediately, right?

Any good reason for the strong restrictions?

Comment: The tag synonym system is pretty broken, as it is. It currently requires moderator intervention for almost all meaninful changes. I'm pretty sure this request is a duplicate (I fully support it, however).